# Connecting to 1.8 HyperSQL database using the newest version of jdbc connector

Tags: java, jdbc, hsqldb

When I try to connect to a HSQL database version 1.8.0.10 using the newest version of HSQL connector 2.4.1 with java (jdbc) It actually rewrites the `nameofdatabase.db.properties` and `nameofdatabase.db.script` files so after that it is not possible to connect to that database with connector of version 1.8.0.10.

Is there any way how to prevent rewriting/editing those files when connecting with newest version of hsql jdbc database connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try connecting with `jdbc:hsqldb:file:nameofdb;readonly=true`